# SolrNet Combine SolrQueryByDistance and SolrQueryByField

Tags: solr, solrnet

I try the following:

```
Dim q = New SolrQueryByField("tag", keyword) With {.Quoted = False} Or New SolrQueryByField("cat", keyword) With {.Quoted = False} Or New SolrQueryByField("shortname", keyword) With {.Quoted = False}

Dim loc As New Location(latitude, longitude)
Dim qgeo = New SolrQueryByDistance("geo", loc, 10)

searchresults = solr.Query(q And qgeo).Cast(Of BusinessSolr)().ToList
```

Which dont work as of:

```
Value of type 'SolrNet.SolrQueryByDistance' cannot be converted to 'SolrNet.AbstractSolrQuery'.
```

(q and qgeo)

Any idea, on how to do a combination of a fieldquery with a distance ?
If possible in VB.NET. Tks a lot

btw: I use Solr 4, SolrNet actual version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to recreate your scenario and experienced the same issue. In looking at the source code for SolrQueryByDistance, I see that it does not derive from the AbstractSolrQuery class and that is reason for this error.

Could you use the Distance query as a [Filter Query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) (limiting the results of the main query to only those items that are within the given distance)? If so, you can use the following:

```
Dim q = New SolrQueryByField("tag", keyword) With {.Quoted = False} Or New SolrQueryByField("cat", keyword) With {.Quoted = False} Or New SolrQueryByField("shortname", keyword) With {.Quoted = False}

Dim loc As New Location(latitude, longitude)
Dim options = New QueryOptions() With { _
.FilterQueries = New ISolrQuery() {New SolrQueryByDistance("geo", loc, 10)} _
}

searchresults = solr.Query(q, options).Cast(Of BusinessSolr)().ToList
```